# How can I get asp.net controls to generate W3c compliant html?

Tags: asp.net

I recently ran some of my ASP pages through "HTML Tidy" validation and found that several warnings were generated due to HTML tags not being properly formed i.e. extra closing tags.On investigation it seems that the ASP Menu control which i am using as the left navigation bar is generating this invalid HTML. It seems that the HTML for this control which Microsoft's automatically generates just isn't HTML compliant.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Does anyone know if there is any way of fixing this?

**See Warnings below**

```
line 175 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 175 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 176 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 181 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 192 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 192 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 193 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 198 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 209 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 209 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 210 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 215 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 226 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 226 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 227 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 232 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 243 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 243 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 244 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 249 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 260 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 260 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 261 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 266 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 277 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 277 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 278 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 283 column 48 - Warning: missing </a> before <tr>
line 294 column 41 - Warning: discarding unexpected </a>
line 294 column 45 - Warning: discarding unexpected </td>
line 295 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected </tr>
line 306 column 9 - Warning: missing </span> before <table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this project: http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/